# MySQL ROW_COUNT() not working in Prepare statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rowcount, rows-affected

What I'm doing.

I've a procedure where I'm deleting rows.

I'm getting `var_SelectedIds` as `,` separated `UUID()`

then

```
SET     @var_SQLStr = '';   
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'Delete ');
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'FROM DemoTable');        
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'WHERE DemoTableId IN (''',Replace(var_SelectedIds,',',''','''),'''); ');

-- SELECT @var_SQLStr;
PREPARE stmt FROM @var_SQLStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

What I've alread tried.

```
// This is throwing SQL Syntax ERROR.

SET     @var_SQLStr = '';   
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'Delete ');
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'FROM DemoTable');        
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'WHERE DemoTableId IN (''',Replace(var_SelectedIds,',',''','''),'''); ');
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,' SELECT ROWS_COUNT() INTO @var_AffectedRows; ');

-- SELECT @var_SQLStr;
PREPARE stmt FROM @var_SQLStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/prepare.html)

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

I also tried

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- Other statements here

SET     @var_SQLStr = '';   
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'Delete ');
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'FROM DemoTable');        
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'WHERE DemoTableId IN (''',Replace(var_SelectedIds,',',''','''),'''); ');

-- SELECT @var_SQLStr;
PREPARE stmt FROM @var_SQLStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @var_AffectedRows
COMMIT;

SELECT @var_AffectedRows AS NoOfRowsDeleted; // 0 output
```

I'm not able to get how may rows got deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` right after `EXECUTE` and before `DEALLOCATE...`

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- Other statements here

SET     @var_SQLStr = '';   
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'Delete ');
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,'FROM DemoTable');        
SET     @var_SQLStr = CONCAT(@var_SQLStr ,' WHERE DemoTableId IN (''',Replace(var_SelectedIds,',',''','''),'''); ');
/*you need an additional whitespace here---^ */


-- SELECT @var_SQLStr;
PREPARE stmt FROM @var_SQLStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @var_AffectedRows;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT @var_AffectedRows; /*TADAAA!*/

COMMIT;
```

Comment: ay idea how to get select statment query count without found_rows?..because row_count is return -1 for select statment